# Yotpo reviews and star ratings not loading on route change - angular 5+

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, rating, review

In my angular app, I have integrated yotpo rating and review widget in an angular page of the product. But on route change to another page , the widgets are missing. the scripts are loaded properly, but the widgets are gone. on page reload , it comes back too.
Below is the html code for rating

```
<div class="yotpo bottomLine" data-appkey="<appkey>"
    data-domain="<domain>" data-product-id="<productId>"
    data-name="<productName>" data-url="<Url>">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

after the page init , just call a method initWidgets of yotpo to refresh the widgets as shown below, can be called in ngoninit or ngafterviewinit

```
if (typeof window['yotpo'] !== 'undefined') {
      window['yotpo'].initWidgets();
}
```